# Google Cloud Functions give back Result even when an Error is thrown

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have a callable Google Cloud Function which I call in the frontend like this:

```
  const register = this.$fireFunc.httpsCallable('registerForTournament');

  register(this.$route.params.id)
    .then(result => {
      console.log(result);
      this.$store.commit('tournaments/addRegistered', {
        id: this.tournament.id,
        user: { uid: this.user.uid, displayName: this.user.displayName }
      });
      this.loadingRegister = false;
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log('no error???');
      this.$toast.error(error);
      this.loadingRegister = false;
    });
```

Now the function gets called and brings back the following

`data: { code: "cancelled", details: null }`

But the function should trigger the error if this happens no? 
Here is one example on how I throw an Error in my Function:

```
if (!userObject.displayName) {
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError('cancelled', 'The Player has no display Name defined.');
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest dumping/logging the value of userObject and seeing what it contains.  I'm also thinking that your cloud function is going to be called as an ExpressJS callback being passed in a request and response object.  It is up to you to send back a response by calling response.status() and response.send().  You might also want to look at the REST traffic to see what is actually being returned.

Comment: Since we can't see what the Cloud Function is actually doing, it's impossible to say if the client is getting the correct response.  Please update your question to show all the relevant code so we can see what's going on here.  We should be able to reproduce the behavior you're seeing.